# CORS vue.js with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I am using:

- vue.js 2
- vue-route
- vuetify
- firebase
- vue-pdf

My project involves reading pdf (novels) from firebase. my pdf files are stored in a bucket and assigned to a novel_url string in firebase. My main problem is CORS whenever I try to read any pdf file in my database I get this error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/(urlpath)' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I have used this chrome plugin Moesif CORS. When it is on, I am able to see the pdf file in my page. So my code works, but the CORS problem is what prevents it from displaying the file.
I have looked into this [solution](https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-deal-with-cors-error-on-vue-cli-3-d78c024ce8d3) and add the following into my development code:

```
module.exports = {
    // options...
    devServer: {
      proxy: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/'
    }
  }
```

I also deployed the site to netlify but still problem still exists. I was wondering if I am actually doing something wrong? any help is much appreciated.

Code for reading:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Navbar />
    <v-container fluid>
      <h1>تقرأ الان {{novel.title}}</h1>
      <div class="novel-display">
        <!-- <pdf src="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/wcrjf9qPTCKXV3hMXDwK" :page="1"></pdf> -->
        <pdf :src="novel.novel_url" :page="1"></pdf>
      </div>
      <p>{{novel.novel_url}}</p>
    </v-container>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import pdf from "vue-pdf";
import db from "../firebase/init";

export default {
  name: "Read",
  components: {
    Navbar,
    Footer,
    pdf
  },
  data() {
    return {
      novel: null
    };
  },
  created() {
    let ref = db
      .collection("Novels")
      .where("novel_slug", "==", this.$route.params.novel_slug);
    ref.get().then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        // console.log(doc.data());
        this.novel = doc.data();
        this.novel.id = doc.id;
      });
    });
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.novel-display {
  border-style: solid;
}
</style>
```

Comment: are you able to communicate to firebase in any other capacity?

Comment: @PavlosKaralis if you mean, I can get data from firebase, yes. I can pull all my data, it's just the pdf file won't load and it's not borken or anything. in fact, I have tried to load this pdf file from this website [link](https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/wcrjf9qPTCKXV3hMXDwK) and I can read with no problem in my application. I know it's weird.

Comment: Can you share the code used to read the PDF file?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I have edited my question and added the code. Please refer to it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it seems that you download the file via a download URL, your problem most probably comes from the fact that "to download data **directly in the browser**, you must configure your Cloud Storage bucket for cross-origin access (CORS)", as explained in the Cloud Storage [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#cors_configuration).

You need to configure it with the `gsutil` command line tool, as explained in the doc referred to above.

Comment: Thank you I will look into the documentation and see.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your time. That fixed my problem. Thank you again.